# How to Iteratively Store Multiple API Calls into a useState Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a list of names inside an array that I need to get data for.

My goal is to use a for-loop that will iteratively perform an API call for each name in the list, with the data from every call being stored into an object inside a Person (`useState`) array. So far I've put together a component but it seems to cause the entire site to become **glitchy** and **malfunction**.

I believe it may be coming from the way I've used the loop inside the `useEffect`, but I'm not entirely sure. Is there a better approach to implementing the component below?

```
function API_CALL(){
    const [Person, SetInfo] = useState([
        {
            age:'',
            occupation:''
        }
    ])  
   
    const names = [
      "bob",
      "alice",
      "jerry",
      "steve",
      "tracy",
      "hank"
    ]
  
    useEffect(() => {
      for(let i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
            fetch('https://api.userfacesite.com/api/v3/data/' + names[i], { 
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json', 
              'Path': '/',
            }
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json=> 
                SetInfo([...person, {age:json.person.age, occupation:json.person.occupation}])
            );
        } 
    },[Person]);
  
    return(
      <div>
        {JSON.stringify(Person)}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementaion can be better with some changes.

First, you need a function to call your API's which can be implemented with `useCallback` hook or with a regular function outside of `useEffect`, also you need a `catch` block for failure API call:

```
function fetchData (name) {
  fetch('https://api.userfacesite.com/api/v3/data/' + name, { 
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json', 
      'Path': '/',
    }
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json=> SetInfo(prevState => 
      ([...prevState, {age:json.person.age, occupation:json.person.occupation}])))
    .catch(error => // do a proper action on error case)
}
```

**Note:** for adding previous data, use `prevState` inside of your `setInfo`.
You have faced some issues here because every time the `person` array gets changes and causes triggers the `useEffect`.

**Note:** use standard names for creating and setting the state, also use same names:

```
const [persons, setPersons] = useState()
```

Now, time to call the `fetchData` function on your `names` array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  names.forEach(name => fetchData(name))
}, []) 
// with an empty array of dependencies, the hook will only invoke on component did mount once.
```

**Optionally:**

You may need to render the `persons` array (an array of objects) on the page, the example below shows this **sample** implementation:

```
return(
  <div>
    {
      persons.map( person => (
        <div>Name: {person.name}</div>
        <p> age: {person.age} </p>
        // and so on for the rest ...
      ))
    }
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Do you know how I could properly display all the persons array objects after every api call has been made for the names?

Comment: yes of course, but what would you like to display? I suggest you create another question since the above question post's title is different from your current question. I need some details to answer properly but it can not be achieved within comments @subprimeloads best regards.

Comment: as a quick answer, you have the "person" variable, just need to map throughout it and return some HTML syntax using JSX to demonstrate your data on the page. for example: "{persons.map(person => (<p>{person.name}</p>))}" @subprimeloads

Comment: I've updated my answer and added some sample code, feel free to ask questions in the comments or create another post (question) with your exact details. thanks @subprimeloads